# Compare two different tags in Eclipse's CVS plugin

Tags: eclipse, cvs

It is very easy to make eclipse compare the current local state of the source tree with some specific tag, but I cannot find an option to use Eclipse's diff capabilities to compare two different tags.

Suppose I have the tags TAG1 and TAG2, and TAG2 is the lattest. I can only compare my current status with TAG1 or TAG2, but not TAG1 against TAG2.

Is it possible to achieve this in Eclipse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to select the two tags from the relevant Version node in the CVS Repositories view and use the context menu to start the Compare.